# Drupal advanced forum - different styles for different forums

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

With Advanced Forum on Drupal 7, how can I apply different styles to different forum posts, depending upon which forum they are in? Although I can see how to style different forums, there doesn't seem to be any way of using a different style per post depending upon the forum it is in, as there is no CSS class added denoting the posts forum.

Answer (score 1):

On further investigation I believe this can be done with a combination of assigning a path to a post via pathauto, and the Context module, which can add CSS depending on the path.